# Messagesid from twilio studio flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Is there any way to get messagesid from studio flow where the sms is sent to the user via the widget?

I am getting below ids but not messagesid

```
[sid] => FNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[accountSid] => ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[flowSid] => FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[contactSid] => FCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You should see the SMS Messaging SID under the widget that sent the SMS. You can view this under the Studio Execution logs for that flow (say under your custom named Send Message widget).